# Python urlib not work in ipv6 machine

Tags: python, urllib

i make this py func :

```
def gethtml( aa):
#print (aa)
f = urllib.request.urlopen(aa)
return str(f.read())
```

in python to get html source work good ,but in pc use ipv6 it not work ,
how can i make it work in both pc with ip4 & ip6

i am new with python :P , i was code with autoit it was easy just one func work in all pc 
and if error it return "" 
but in python i must make exeption for error 
however my #2 questions is there any easy way to get html source that will work fine with no error and in all pc .

Thank you :) .

Comment: How doesn't it work? This is likely to do with the configuration of the machine you're running on/the machine you're connecting to (or a combination of both) and nothing to do with Python...

Comment: the question seems daft but can you ping when in ipv6?

Comment: hi , yeh every thing work normal ,ping ... anlso some scripts in autoit that use tcp socket , or curl . work normal . but this fun in python not work .